# R: Adding the norm of beta as a column

Tags: r, matrix

I want to add a new column called **norm** (which holds the norm of **value**) into data frame **tmp**. If the column `variable==1` compute norm for `value` where *variable==1*. If the column `variable==2`compute norm for `value` where *variable==2*.

Here is the data frame:

```
      coef variable      value
1     1        1  0.9591502
2     2        1  5.3128176
3     3        1 12.4926498
4     4        1 17.7088466
5     5        1  4.7635561
6     1        2  7.8381375
7     2        2  6.0122541
8     3        2  9.2607897
9     4        2  6.7421873
10    5        2  4.2404777
```

Here is the code, so far:

```
   #generating some values
set.seed(19875)
n=10
p=30
real_p=15
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
y=as.matrix(apply(x[, 1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n))
beta=as.matrix(rep(0,ncol(x)))
n_iter=2
value1=matrix(0,30,n_iter)
value2=matrix(0,30,n_iter)

#the important part 
for(k in 1:n_iter){
  beta=matrix(rexp(beta, rate=.1), nrow = ncol(x))       #generating beta values 
  value1[,k]=beta                                        #storing beta to a matrix 30x1
  value2[,k]=norm(beta)                                  #storing norm as a matrix 30x1
  tmp <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(value1))
  tmp$coef <- row.names(tmp)                             #adding column coef
  tmp <- reshape::melt(tmp, id = "coef")                 #adding col variable and value
  tmp$variable <- as.numeric(gsub("V", "", tmp$variable))#removing V
}
tmp
```

If I add a new column called *norm* with the function **melt**,`tmp$norm=melt(value2, id="variable")` I get some **norm.X1** and **norm.X2** columns which I don't need.

```
  coef variable      value norm.X1 norm.X2 norm.value
1     1        1  0.9591502       1       1   331.9455
2     2        1  5.3128176       2       1   331.9455
3     3        1 12.4926498       3       1   331.9455
4     4        1 17.7088466       4       1   331.9455
5     5        1  4.7635561       5       1   331.9455
```

How can I add the norm without those new columns added?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit your question with your answer. If you found the solution yourself, you are welcome to answer below, otherwise you can chose another members answer as the one that helped you by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Questions that have been edited to include a solution may be rolled back to the previous state.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs oh I didn't know that, I will add it then below. Thank you.